# Using DataSource to connect to SQLite with (Xerial) sqlite-jdbc driver

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, datasource

[Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/overview/index.html) says there are 2 ways to connect to database thru JDBC: with **DriverManager** class (old, not recommended) and with **DataSource** class.

I undestand how to do it with DriverManager:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:mytest.db");
...
```

**But I cannot find how to use DataSource for SQLite thru JDBC. Does SQLite (or JDBC driver providers for it, I don't know how to call it correctly) support using DataSource at all?**

I am using [xerial/sqlite-jdbc](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) driver to use SQLite from java (https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc)

My best guess is that I shall use org.sqlite.SQLiteDataSource class (it comes in sqlite-jdbc-3.15.1.jar for Xerial sqlite-jdbc driver), but how? And is it so? I also guess, that how to do it shall be in Xerial driver docs, but they give only example of how to connect using DriverManager.

**So I am asking kind help of guru to confirm that [this](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) Xerial driver/jar doesn't support DataSource syntax, or to give example how to do it, or to suggest alternative driver with DataSource support (for SQLite from Java), or advice otherwise...**

[Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/overview/index.html)

> JDBC Driver Manager —  The JDBC DriverManager class defines objects
>   which can connect Java applications to a JDBC driver. DriverManager
>   has traditionally been the backbone of the JDBC architecture. It is
>   quite small and simple.
>
> The Standard Extension packages javax.naming and javax.sql let you use
>   a DataSource object registered with a Java Naming and Directory
>   Interface™ (JNDI) naming service to establish a connection with a data
>   source. You can use either connecting mechanism, but using a
>   DataSource object is recommended whenever possible.

Answer (score 10):

> My best guess is that I shall use org.sqlite.SQLiteDataSource class (it comes in sqlite-jdbc-3.15.1.jar for Xerial sqlite-jdbc driver),

Yes, that seems likely.

> but how?

I just tried the following and it worked for me:

```java
package com.example.sqlite.sqlite_test;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.sqlite.SQLiteDataSource;

public class SqliteTestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SQLiteDataSource ds = new SQLiteDataSource();
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:sqlite::memory:");
        try (Connection conn = ds.getConnection()) {
            System.out.println("Connected.");
            String sql = 
                    "SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM \"sqlite_master\"";
            try (
                    Statement s = conn.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(sql)) {
                rs.next();
                System.out.printf(
                        "The \"sqlite_master\" table contains %d row(s).%n", 
                        rs.getInt(1));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I needed `ds.setUrl("jdbc:sqlite:/path/to/table.sqlite");` to make it work with my database.

Comment: @dauer - Are you saying that `ds.setDatabaseName("/path/to/table.sqlite");` didn't work for you?

Comment: Yes, the setDatabaseName(...) command doesn't work for me, I just tried it again with the full path and the relative path: I always get an Error (https://pastebin.com/uDYXRmHG).

Comment: Note, that I changed the code to read from a table stored previously in the file. If I read from sqlite_master it always works. (I guess using setDatabaseName just creates a new in memory DB instead of accessing a file.)

Comment: @dauer - Aha. I see what you mean. Thanks for the correction. I have updated the answer.