# Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC") vs JDBC.PREFIX to load JDBC class

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

We had recently moved to building projects using Maven. Earlier, all the JARs were added in libs folder and added to classpath. While moving to the Maven build, I missed to add a dependency to the 'sqlite-jdbc'. This library is required to read data from a local .db3 file.

As the 'org.sqlite.JBDC' class was loaded by calling the code `Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC")`, there was no compilation error and I deployed the WAR file and servlet failed in the server. I was thinking of a way to find the issue at the compilation time itself to avoid any such mistakes in the future. Can I simply call the JDBC.PREFIX to load the JDBC, so that, If I forget to add the dependency to the pom.xml file, I can find the issue at the compile time, itself?

Is there was difference between `Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC")` vs `JDBC.PREFIX` to load JDBC class?

Comment: What do you mean by `JDBC.PREFIX`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No need for `Class.forName`

There is no generally no need to call [`Class.forName`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)).

Such calls were used in the early years. Modern Java was changed so that JDBC drivers are automatically loaded and registered with the JVM via the Java [Service Provider Interface (SPI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_provider_interface) facility.

If you are using books or tutorials advising `Class.forName`, you may want to obtain more up-to-date learning materials.

## `DataSource`

Furthermore, in Servlet work you generally should not be explicitly accessing the JDBC driver.

Setting the database server address, username, and password would require hard-coding text. When the deployment sysadmins change the IP address, or rotate passwords, your code breaks. You would then have to modify your source code, re-compile, and re-deploy.

Instead, you should externalize such configuration details.

For SQLite, see [*Using DataSource to connect to SQLite with (Xerial) sqlite-jdbc driver*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41230234/642706).

## JNDI

You can externalize database configuration by using the the [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html) interface. After obtaining a `DataSource` object at runtime, make database connections by calling its [`getConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html#getConnection()) method. That `DataSource` object holds the database server address, username, password, and all other settings needed to make a connection to the database.

Obtain a `DataSource` object at runtime by using [JNDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Naming_and_Directory_Interface). Your Servlet container may act as the naming/directory server to provide the `DataSource` object, if your sysadmin so configures it. Or the `DataSource` can be obtained via JNDI from an external server such as an [LDAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol) server.

Again, the beauty of using `DataSource` and JNDI is that you as the Servlet programmer need not be involved, or even informed, when the deployment details change.

## JDBC driver location

For Servlet work, you generally do not bundle the JDBC driver with your app.

Instead, the JDBC driver goes into a folder managed by your Servlet container. Study the documentation for your particular Servlet container. For [*Apache Tomcat*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat), see [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13175611/642706).

In development, your [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) may need access to the JDBC driver to compile. If so, in your Maven POM, mark the dependency with a `<scope>provided</scope>` element. This tag tells Maven to omit that dependency from the final build because the dependency will already be present (provided) at runtime.

If you insist on bundling your JDBC driver within the WAR file of your web app, then see the important [Comment by Mark Rotteveel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71274313/class-fornameorg-sqlite-jdbc-vs-jdbc-prefix-to-load-jdbc-class#comment125987047_71274414).

This topic has been addressed many times on Stack Overflow. [Search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20java%20jdbc%20driver%20location%20folder&t=ipad&ia=web) to learn more.

Comment: Given the OP is deploying a WAR which includes the driver, they will actually need to call `Class.forName` to load the driver (assuming they are using `DriverManager` and not some `DataSource` that does the loading for them). Automatic driver loading only works when the driver is on the initial classpath. Drivers that are in a web application classpath are not loaded automatically (at least, not in for example Tomcat).